# Autokey gtk: how to copy current line to clipboard?

Tags: autokey

Anyone familiar with autokey-gtk that knows how to copy the entire line which my cursor is currently at? Or more specific: **how to add the current line to the clipboard?**

I can make a script that paste what is selected by the mouse. But I do not want to use the mouse.

Comment: In a word processor? In an editor? A line on a web page?

Comment: In a word processor. Sorry, I was not clear about that.

Comment: Still this is not clear in your question. Please edit your question to add all relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

It's quit old post, but it was found by google search and therefore maybe it helps other. Paste text into clipboard can be done with clipboard.fill_clipboard("TEST")

https://autokey.github.io/api/gtkclipboard.html#autokey.scripting.clipboard_gtk.GtkClipboard.fill_clipboard